# Does the list have any numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
my_list = [12,8,0,4,7,21,27,"O",29,3,"X","O","X","X"]
```

This list gets updated throughout the program. Every time it gets updated, I want to check to see if it contains only numbers or only strings, or both. What can I use to do that?
**I need to check all the elements in the list. Any suggestion? **


**With Explanation on how the code works please.**

Thank you all for your help.I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you need to check all the elements in the list? Can't you just check the items that were updated?

Comment: Why does your list contain inhomogeneous data in the first place? That's usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Gabe I must check every element to see if they are all numbers or strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [`type`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) and [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
>>> my_list = [12,8,0,4,7,21,27,"O",29,3,"X","O","X","X"]
>>> set(map(type, my_list))
{<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>}
>>> set(map(type, my_list)) == {int, str}
True
>>> set(map(type, my_list)) == {int}
False
>>> set(map(type, my_list)) == {str}
False

>>> my_list = [12,8,0,4,7,21,27]
>>> set(map(type, my_list))
{<class 'int'>}

>>> my_list = ["X", "O", "X", "X"]
>>> set(map(type, my_list))
{<class 'str'>}
>>> set(map(type, my_list)) == {str}
True
```

`type` returns the type of an object:

```
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
>>> type('X')
<class 'str'>
```

`map(type, seq)` apply `type` to the `seq`:

```
>>> map(type, [1, 2, 3, 'X'])
<map object at 0x7fc763de6e90>
>>> list(map(type, [1, 2, 3, 'X']))
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>]
>>> # Using `set`, you can get unique types.
>>> set(map(type, [1, 2, 3, 'X']))
{<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>}
```

**NOTE** (@lvc's comment)

> This will break if you happen to have **subclases** of `int` or `str` in the
>   list. This is probably unlikely with those classes specifically, but
>   it means it doesn't generalise very well.

Comment: I want to check using an if statement only.

Comment: Great elegant, intuitive solution.

Comment: @Andy: What is that supposed to mean? What aren't you allowed to use? What counts as using more than an if statement?

Comment: @Andy, `if` statement only? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @user2357112, Sorry, I fixed the comment.

Comment: @falsetru Inside a function I am trying to determine if the list contains all integers or all strings. If it contains all strings, then the function would return True, else, it would return false.

Comment: @Andy: You can use `if set(map(type, my_list)) == {str}: return True ....` or use `any`/`all` as other suggested.

Comment: This will break if you happen to have subclases of `int` or `str` in the list. This is probably unlikely with those classes specifically, but it means it doesn't generalise very well.

Comment: @falsetru You dont even need `if` simply `return set(map(type, my_list)) == {str}`. And I didnt downvote.

Comment: @thefourtheye, Thank you for comment. I used it because I'm not sure what OP want in another case.

Comment: @lvc, Thank you for comment. I added your comment as note in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `isinstance` and `all`:

```
>>> all(isinstance(x, (int, str)) for x in my_list)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The isinstance function tells if a element x is a instance of a class. So, isinstance(2, int) evaluates to true.

Using map we can apply isinstance to every member of the list, generating a list with the results. So:

```
map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), my_list)
```

evaluates to:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

If you just want to know if there is a string on the list, you can do something like that:

```
True in map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), my_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and editing the question again. You are such a nice person. Thank you for trying to help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
my_list = [12,8,0,4,7,21,27,"O",29,3,"X","O","X","X"]
if any(isinstance(i, (str, int)) != True for i in my_list):
    print "There is something else in the list!"
```

The `any()` statement is equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

So pretty much, the code is equivalent to:

```
for item in my_list:
    if not isinstance(i, (str, int)):
        print item, "is not a string or list!"
        break
```

Comment: interesting way of writing `all` :)

Comment: This is such a unique answer. I am not that advanced with Python, but thank you very much for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think `filter` is more suitable.

```
result = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), my_list)
if result: print 'find integer'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of another alternative:

```
totint = sum(isinstance(x, int) for x in my_list)
if totint == 0:
    print "all are strings"
elif totint == len(my_list):
    print "all are ints"
else:
    print "mixed"
```

Comment: I never thought of that. This is a very special way of writing it. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

And another alternative, should be quicker than scanning the whole list:

```
if not any(isinstance(x, int) for x in my_list):
    print "all are strings"
elif not any(isinstance(x, str) for x in my_list):
    print "all are ints"
else:
    print "mixed"
```

Or even better:

```
if any(isinstance(x, int) for x in my_list):
    if any(isinstance(x, str) for x in my_list):
        print "mixed"
    else:
        print "all are ints"
else:
    print "all are strings"
```